# QT Designer: Moving & Resizing widgets while respecting window rescaling PyQT5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, resize, qt-designer

**TLDR:** QT Designer won't let me move and resize widgets while respecting window scaling. I would like to have the right most button move closer to the edge of the window when dragging it from image 1 to 2, aka keeping the proportions.

I am using PyQT5 with QT Designer. I am trying to manually organize (move & resize) my widgets, but both of my approaches (explained next) fail.

When I use a grid layout, I can scale the widgets by changing the window size by dragging its edges (as expected... great!). But when I use layouts, I cannot change the relative positions of widgets. When using layouts, I also can't drag the edges of an individual widget to resize it within the window (bummer, and kind of important for building my UI).

On the flip side, when I don't use any layout, I can move and resize individual widgets freely (yay!). But without using a layout, my widgets no longer scale to fit window size.

**My question is**, how can I both move and resize widgets in QT Designer? I would think I could do it in QT Designer itself and not rely on messing with PyQT5, since that would complicate even minor changes and isn't drag and drop what QT Designer is for?

Attached are a couple of screenshots to show what I mean pictorially. The first 2 photos show what goes on in the case with no layout. I made the window bigger but my widgets stayed in the same spot with the same size. The 3rd screenshot shows what happens when I employ a grid layout. I can't resize any widget, nor can I move them much.

In other words, is there a more effective approach to moving and resizing with QT Designer that solves both of these failures?

**I would like to have the right most button move closer to the edge of the window when dragging it from image 1 to 2, aka keeping the proportions.**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you asking how can you have a layout similar to the first image (so, with ***lots*** of empty space), but keeping the proportions when resizing?

Comment: Your question is very generic, could you point out that you hope to obtain in the specific case, that is, an image of how the widgets should be displayed in different window sizes since your requirement is currently confusing, I understand the probable limitations of the layouts but I can't understand the exact behavior you expect

Comment: @musicamante That's exactly what I am looking to do. I would like to have the right most button move closer to the edge of the window when dragging it from image 1 to 2, aka keeping the proportions.

Comment: @Gnumbertester As I thought. I was already answering about that, but please consider for future reference that having a clear explanation of the wanted result really help us to better (and faster) understand where is the problem and how we can eventually answer.

Comment: @eyllanesc I appreciate the feedback. The exact behavior I expect is having the widgets move with the screen resizing. In the first and second photos, I placed those widgets there by hand, but when I drag the window to resize in the second case, they don't move proportional to the resizing. I don't know how I could provide you a snapshot of an ideal organization since I am currently unable to make one?

Comment: @musicamante I appreciate that and will do my part by adding that point of clarification to the post as an edit, so it is clearer for others on this post.

Comment: @Gnumbertester Let's say that the initial window has a size of 200x200 and the button is in position 50x50 and size 40x40, if the size of the window changes to 300x250 then what should be the size and position of the button for that case?

Comment: @eyllanesc In that case, since I expect size and position to grow proportionally, the size would 60x50 and the position 75, 62.5. I found those numbers by multiplying by the change in x,y directions. So since 200(1.5) = 300 and 200(1.25) = 250, so 40x1.5 = 60 and 40x1.25 = 50. Same for the position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While overcrowded UIs are usually not a good idea, having lots of empty space is rarely better. Layout managers consider this aspect, and try to *optimize* the available space by making the widgets use as much space as possible (assuming that they can be resized).
That said, there are obviously lots of situations for which a big window with lots of space is fine (for instance, a login access interface that is big enough to get the attention).

What is important to understand is that a layout manager, as the name says, ***manages*** the layout, and it does that by *a lot* of complex computations, based on the widget on which it is installed and all the size hints/policies/constraints of *all* its child items, recursively. If you have some requirements about how some widget should be able to resize, you must specify them.

Whenever *any* interface is going to be created, and especially if UX matters are being considered (as they should) and there's also a lot of empty space that should be proportionally used, there are at least two important steps:

1. exactly understand how widgets should be placed (position, size and proportions) in "normal" conditions on a layout;
2. think about those sizes and position should change when the container is resized;

The first point seems quite explanatory, but to even create a basic interface that considers empty areas using layouts is not that simple.
Depending on the situation, a grid layout might suffice, but in certain conditions you might need to use *nested* layouts.

In your specific case, a grid could be enough, but to ensure that proper spacings and proportion are going to be maintained, you need to use *spacer items*.

I've prepared a basic UI example for your case: the proportions might not be completely correct, but it's a start.

Here's how it looks at a normal size:

[image: Normal size window]

And that's how it looks when it's bigger:

[image: Bigger size window]

As you can see, I added spacers: there's one for *each* side near the edges, which is required to ensure that a proper "border margin" is maintained, then another two for the spacing between the two buttons; since the grid becomes 5x5, the "cell" position of the two central spacers might be in any place, as long as the vertical is in the central row and the horizontal in the central column.

Now, the proportions of widgets and spacings are achieved through the following:

- both buttons have a `Preferred` size policy (both vertical and horizontal); this ensures that the layout knows that it can make them bigger if there's enough space for them, but without making them occupy *all* the available space;
- the size policy of the top left button has a *stretch* of 1 (again, both vertical and horizontal), while it's 2 for the bottom right one; in this way, they second button will always ***try*** to be twice the width and height of the first;
- the layout (accessible by clicking on the central widget) has also a column stretch of 2 set for the third column (the one in the middle); considering the above, the result will be that the layout will try to make the space in the middle as much wide as the bottom right button;

Note that the row or column stretch of the buttons can (and sometimes *should*) be directly set on the layout when using a grid.
Also consider that the spacers at the edges are basic QSpacerItems, which have very limited features (the minimum width/height and size policy), and if you want a bigger and proportional margin, you have to set it in the stretch. Another possibility is to use empty QWidgets instead of spacers.

Based on the above, a better choice is to actually set the stretches of the grid layout:

```
vertical (rows):      1, 2, 1, 4, 1
horizontal (columns): 1, 2, 4, 4, 1
```

<sup>Remember that the stretch values are *relative proportions*, if you want more precise sizes, use greater values.</sup>

Obviously, you could also set maximum sizes for any of the widgets, in case you don't want to exceed a certain size.

I'll attach the original file (with the stretch set on the widgets only) so I'll leave to you to alter those values and see what happens.

Finally, remember that if you add another widget that has *one* of the size policies that is not `Preferred` or `Ignored`, the layout will react accordingly. Try to add a button to an empty grid in the same row or column of an existing button, and you'll see the results.

Here's the basic UI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>806</width>
    <height>507</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout" columnstretch="0,0,2,0,0">
    <item row="1" column="2">
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>40</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="2">
     <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>40</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item row="4" column="3">
     <spacer name="verticalSpacer_3">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>40</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="4">
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>40</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>1</horstretch>
        <verstretch>1</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="3">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>2</horstretch>
        <verstretch>2</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>...</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>40</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>40</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>806</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

While there are fundamentally just three basic layout managers (QFormLayout and QStackedLayout are a bit different), and they are very simple, learning how to use them requires a lot of time and experience. Also, knowing how the size hints and policies work is *very* important to better understand their behavior. I strongly suggest you to do *a lot* of experiments both in Designer and also by creating UI from code.
For **learning** purposes, you can create the UI in Designer, export it using `pyuic` and study its contents. But, remember, do not **ever**, ***never*** edit those files for production code. Read more about their usage on the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: Thank you for this extremely comprehensive answer. I will need some time to fully digest this but I have already read it over twice. I did upload the UI file into designer, but when I try to drag an edge of a spacer to resize it, the size change does not hold. Is there a reason why I can't manually mess around with the widget sizes? I'll review the answer again to see if the answer to that is contained in it.

Comment: Or does all stretching need to get done in the UI file itself?

Comment: "Is there a reason why I can't manually mess around with the widget sizes?": that's written in the very beginning: layout **manage** the sizes. When widgets are inside layouts, the small squares can only be used to change the way those items occupy the layout: for grid layout, if you have a widget in a cell grid and you try to resize it on its right edge (assuming that cell is empty), it means that the widget will occupy *both* cells. If you want to set a *specific* size for the spacer, then change its minimum size properties or set the column or row stretch in the layout as explained above.

Comment: No, you are not supposed to modify the UI file (as much as the pyuic generated files), all changes have to be done from Designer, using the properties of the widgets or their layouts. I recommend to create a new (new! don't edit the current one!), very basic example, put there 4 buttons in a 2x2 grid and set a grid layout, then start to change the size policies of the widgets and the properties of the layout.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to implement the proportion then:

- Use additional QWidgets (which are invisible by default but for my demo I will set background colors) or QSpacerItem,
- Use stretch factors that meet the condition, and
- Set the sizePolice of all widgets to Ignored.

The gridlayout will use that information to rescale the geometry.

For my demo window has a size of 200x200 and the button is in position 50x50 and size 40x40.

[image]

- For the widget on the left side you must set the horizontal stretch factor to 40
- For the central on the right side you must set the horizontal stretch factor to 50 and the horizontal stretch factor to 50.
- For the widget on the right side you must set the horizontal stretch factor to 90(200 - 50 -40)
- For the widget on the top side you must set the vertical stretch factor to 50.
- For the widget on the bottom side you must set the vertical stretch factor to 90(200 - 50 -40).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>593</width>
    <height>439</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <widget class="QWidget" name="top" native="true">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Ignored" vsizetype="Ignored">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>50</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(85, 255, 127);</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QWidget" name="left" native="true">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Ignored" vsizetype="Ignored">
        <horstretch>50</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Ignored" vsizetype="Ignored">
        <horstretch>40</horstretch>
        <verstretch>40</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="2">
     <widget class="QWidget" name="right" native="true">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Ignored" vsizetype="Ignored">
        <horstretch>110</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 85, 255);</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="1">
     <widget class="QWidget" name="bottom" native="true">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Ignored" vsizetype="Ignored">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>110</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(85, 255, 255);</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>593</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```